# Materialize CSS Sidenav Menu Items hidden

Tags: materialize

I am using materializecss. I am using a sidenav. The issue i have is:
1. When the menu items are more than the screen height the menu items get hidden
2. Same happens with the dropdown menus.
Any idea on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

That is by design. The sidenav is scrollable, allowing a full menu to be displayed on mobile devices in both orientations. The same thing applies to dropdowns. "Fixing" it would be to limit the number of items you place in the menu or dropdown, but that is usually self-defeating.